# How can I add action = "/#" to a button without using <form>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I add `action = "/#"` to a button without using `<form>`?
For example, I want to do

```
<button type="submit" action = "/logout" class="btn btn-default">Logout</button>
```

instead of:

```
<form action = "/logout">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Logout</button>
</form>
```

Here is the current code:

```
<div class="navbar-form navbar-right btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Score</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">Favorites</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Logout</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you just use a link? `<a href="/#" class="btn btn-default">Logout</a>` - or do you need to actually perform some actions to log a user out?

Comment: I think you will need javascript

Comment: Can I ask why exactly you don't want to use the `<form>` tag? Also, are you familiar with using javascript / jQuery enough to attempt performing this action using javascript? A more complete summary of what you are trying to do will help us assist you more.

Comment: Thank you guys. I didn't want to use <form> because for some reason it breaks my app. The app is mostly built using Python and an MVC framework called Pylot, but ended up using jQuery and it worked great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use action attribute on a button it only works with HTML form. `type="submit"` is used on a form element to submit the form data. An element with this type will appear as a button by default.

If you don't want to use HTML form you can use anchor tag to send user on any page. You can also do it with JavaScript or jQuery